# JFS Compression issues

Tags: linux, filesystems

Using NTFS filesystem on linux I am able to have a partition that is either compressing the data or not. To create this partition I can just use mkntfs.

When looking for a similar thing with the JFS filesystem I cannot find a way of turning on compression. Is it even possible to have an uncompressed JFS partition? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFS_%28file_system%29), JFS1 on AIX is the only place you'll get JFS compression.

Comment: Of course it figures that the one place that I overlook is the most obvious. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Just so you know, I don't necessarily rely on wikipedia as authoritative, but I couldn't find any reference confirming jfs on linux compression was possible.